# datetime in oracle where query in c# application

Tags: c#, oracle

Below is my Oracle query written in my c# application to fetch records that matches particular date. Query executes successfully, but returns 0 records even thoug there are records matching today's date.

```
 System.Text.StringBuilder sbQuery = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
 sbQuery.Append("select id from temp where activity_datetime=:mDate");
 System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand oraCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
 oraCmd.CommandText = strSQL;
 oraCmd.Parameters.Add("mDate", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.DateTime);
 oraCmd.Parameters[0].Value = DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString();
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(oraCmd);
 da.Fill(ds);
```

Please let me know what is the error

Thanks

Comment: What is your `oraCmd` looks like when you debug your code after you add the parameter value?

Comment: The problem is in the SQL text: you should filter for interval (activity_datetime >= ...) and (activity_datetime < ...) not for equivalence (activity_datetime == ...)

Answer (score 0):

You are building up the query in the sbQuery StringBuilder, but providing the variable strSQL as the command to the query, so it's presumably a different query to the one you intend.

By the way, the System.Data.OracleClient namespace was deprecated in .NET 4, so you may want to look at alternatives in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

It looks, that the problem is in the SQL text: instead of

```
  sbQuery.Append("select id from temp where activity_datetime=:mDate");
```

you should put it like

```
  sbQuery.Append(
    "select id 
       from temp 
      where (activity_datetime >= Trunc(:mDate)) and 
            (activity_datetime < Trunc(:mDate) + 1)");
```

The reason is that you should ask Oracle for *the range (24 hours)*, not for *exact date and time*